# How to map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C++?

Tags: c++

How to map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C++ ?
Any code snippet...

Comment: Your are blatantly disrespectful. Please address one problem at a time.

Comment: Arguably dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404710/how-to-mount-a-sftp-share-as-a-network-drive-programmatically-in-c among others by this user.

Comment: The polite way to raise attention to your questions on stackoverflow is to place a bounty, not keep re-asking the questions.

Comment: @Sarnold : OK i will keep this in mind.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does what you need: http://dokan-dev.net/en/docs/dokan-readme/